# What is the value of a control qubit as a Controlled-X Gate or Tofolli Gate parameter?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

For example in a Controlled-X or Tofolli gate, qubits can be assigned as control bits. But before the measurement ; what are the values of these qubits in the gate tensor since they can not be 1 or 0 ? Are they used as state vectors ?

Comment: They could be in a superposition of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

A control qubit can be in any state - $|0⟩$ or $|1⟩$ or some superposition of these two, as @Mark S mentioned above. That’s up to you, set them as desired for your needs.

For a control qubit in state $|0⟩$ nothing will happen. For a control qubit in state $|1⟩$ the controlled operation will be applied for sure.

If the control qubit is in some superposition, the controlled operation may or may not occur, but the statevector of the system changes. Consider the following very simple example (a "Bell state") for clarification:

[image]

1. First dotted line ("barrier") - The state of the system is $|00⟩$.
2. Second line - The control qubit is in the $|+⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0⟩ + |1⟩)$ state after applying the **H** gate. The overall state of the system is $|0+⟩$ (I am using little endian notation here as Qiskit does, i.e downmost qubit in the circuit is leftmost qubit in the ket notation).
3. Third line - The overall state of the system is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00⟩ + |11⟩)$. That makes sense because if **q0** is in $|0⟩$ state then nothing happens to **q1** and the overall state of the system is $|00⟩$. If **q0** is in $|1⟩$ state then **q1** is flipped and the overall state of the system is $|11⟩$.